# Webservice @httpPost method authentication

Tags: rest-api, integration, webservices, authentication, apex-webservice

Quick response on this would be helpful. I'm able to send request body from Workbench as source to my org as destination for creation of records. But what i need is how to perform the same operation using Postman tool or something else. Basically i have add authentication on my webservice class(means i have to allow my @httpPost method to access by only those for whom i give permission in my salesforce org based on username and password / Oauth methos.). Its for Webservice class @httpPost method.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What part are you getting stuck on? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I have a Webservice class, which im testing through Workbench.  i want to know how to add security for accessing my webservice class from third party.      where i want something lie below in my webservice class for authentication purpose.                                                                                                       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    String username = 'theusername';
    String password = 'thepasswork';

    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

Comment: If you are calling salesforce service from workbench you will not need to set this , else you need to have either sessionId / Access token to call the service from third party where you can set the header as you have specified in the calling point . Also in this case you need to make sure that third party system is white listed in your company's firewall

Answer (score 2):

This is the way i found out to do, 
I tried this with postman tool.
First enter the below URL with respective parameters and make a request for access token

```
Endpoint url = https://"yourOrgInstance".salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

PARAMETERS

```
client_id  =  3MVG99S6MzYiT5k8Wklml6FnGX5UVDSDSASADSAV.lWcKcPlMhaikiPoapcdX,
client_secret  =  641362283729873987213897123,
username = jayanth@christ.dev,
password  = *********,
grant_type  = password.
```

AFTER OBTAINING THE ACCESS TOKEN

```
Endpoint url = https://"yourOrgInstance".salesforce.com/services/apexrest/StudentsDetails
```

HEADERS

```
Content-Type = application/json,
Authorization = Bearer 00D0l000000Cssm!AQEAQAhRNEsMvWDunFuM7XaPUs58vyI5wWYyLu06I5tUdCmoG3O5FsqRiVuL0JYM6091nUP0UlHGuzN60rBvkTMIiKyEQ6aK
or 
Authorization = Bearer "AccessToken"
```

now add your request body and make a call.